# hiding id and password from nodejs when consuming API

Tags: node.js, node-modules

When I am consuming `API` in `nodejs` with `basic authentication` I need to hard code `id and password`. is there anyway i can hide them. Below is my code and I have hard coded `username` as well as `password`. Can I make at-least password not readable. somebody was saying `token` but I dont know how can I use it.
below is my code

```
var request = require('request');

var url = 'https://50d5a18993c046e585b90bc8cc5e1f80-jcs.oci.cloudonline.ml:443/IMCMCSREST/rest/v1/PlannedCosts'
var user = 'Shrutisharma@xxxx.com';
var pass = 'DDixishruti1234';



// Use POST instead of GET
request.post(
    {
        uri: url,
        form: { username: user, password: pass }
    },
    function (err, httpResponse, body) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error('post failed:', err);
        }
        console.log(body);

    }
);
```

Comment: At first I would like to recommend something like [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). Then there is no need for hardcoding things like passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In development mode, you can use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). In production mode, you should save sensitive information such as API key, password, etc in environment(System) variable

You can access env varaibles using `process.env['varaible']`

This guide might be useful:

https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786

Comment: Just wanted to add that you should never commit your `.env` files to your versioning tool (Github) because your password is still in clear in that file. Considering you have an SSL connection, they are not transmitted in clear, even though you use Basic Auth. So you "just" have to keep the `.env` file safe.